# How to identify the index of a row containing only NaNs in a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, row, nan

I have a 2-dimensional numpy matrix that looks something like this:

```
array = np.array([[nan, nan, 5.1, nan, nan],
                  [nan, 3.2, 1.7, 9.9, nan],
                  [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
                  [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
                  [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

I'd like to identify the index of the first row in the matrix that contains *only* nans. (In this case, that index would be 2.) But I can't figure out how to do it.

I know I can find the indices of *all* the nans by using `np.argwhere(np.isnan(array))`, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Any idea on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close! You can use [`np.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy-all) (or the `np.array` method `all`) along an axis to find entries that are all `nan` e.g.

```py
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan
a = np.array([[nan, nan, 5.1, nan, nan],
              [nan, 3.2, 1.7, 9.9, nan],
              [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
              [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
              [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
np.argwhere(np.isnan(a).all(axis=1))
```

will give you

```py
array([[2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

You can also use a trick with [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy-argmax) here to find the first row where this is `True`

```py
np.isnan(a).all(axis=1).argmax()
```

will give

```
2
```